# $using in powershell to execute a script on remote machine

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a particular script out on a remote machine

```
$script:remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $script:currentnode -Credential $script:cred -ErrorAction Stop
Invoke-Command -Session $script:remoteSession -ScriptBlock {                
    . "$($using:RemotedriveLetter):\SilentInstaller\configureWindows.ps1" -driveLetter $using:RemotedriveLetter      
}
```

but the above code gives the below error

"A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer."

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You need to create the local variable `$RemotedriveLetter` before you can reference it in a remote scriptblock with `$using:`

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen the $RemotedriveLetter is already assigned, i just didn't include that in the code snippet, but that variable does have a local value.